# can we conver hadoop archive files to sequence files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression

I converted few zipped files to sequence files using java mapreduce and java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.

I have few hadoop archive files and want to convert them into sequence files.. is this possible??

If it is possible to convert the HAR files to sequence files.. do we have any package similar to ZipInputStream like "HarInputStream". I tried searching this but coulndt find any result.

Can I use the TextInputStream for the HAR files??

Also is there any way to unarchive the .har files or should I have to read the part files in the .har files directly??

Comment: A Hadoop Archive is essentially just a directory on hdfs. To list it's contents, you can use `hdfs dfs -ls har:///path/to/harfile.har`. To extract the data, you can use `hdfs dfs -cp`

Comment: hdfs dfs -cp /harfile.har/part_file ... this is it right?? 

So can I treat it as a text file to convert it into sequence?

Comment: First try to do a `hdfs dfs -ls har://harfile.har` and see what's inside the har. Then you can copy the file that you want. Notice the `har://` in front of the path.

Comment: this helped.. thansk :) any idea on converting the har files sequence files??